# Yubico OTP with automated registration/getapikey?

Tags: .net, one-time-password, yubico

We like to use Yubico/Yubikeys to enable users to use a 2nd factor in our applications. For this, an administrator has to provision yubikeys to users.

We want to do this in .net and found this library:
https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-dotnet-client/

Now according to this site, we need to register first to get a clientid and an apikey (https://upgrade.yubico.com/getapikey/)

My question is:
Do I have to automate this website call for every Yubikey I want to provision?
Isnt there a supported way to do this via code? How do I un-register a key (if it gets lost or breaks)?

thx
Michi

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to automate this website call for every Yubikey I want to
>   provision?

No, you don't need to to create a new **clientId**/**apiKey** for each Yubikey. You only need that for using Yubico's API ([YubiCloud](https://www.yubico.com/products/services-software/yubicloud/)) in your application.

---

> How do I un-register a key (if it gets lost or breaks)?

To identify a Yubikey, you will use the **publicId**.

> A Yubico OTP is a 44-character, one use, secure, 128-bit encrypted
>   Public ID and Password, near impossible to spoof. The OTP is comprised
>   of two major parts: the first 12 characters remain constant and
>   represent the Public ID of the YubiKey device itself. The remaining 32
>   characters make up a unique passcode for each OTP generated.

[OTPs Explained](https://developers.yubico.com/OTP/OTPs_Explained.html)

So for register a new or remove a old (or lost) Yubikey, you will add or remove that Yubikey from your application.

You can use Yubico's [PublicId](https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-dotnet-client/blob/master/YubicoDotNetClient/IYubicoResponse.cs#L101) after you validate the OTP.

https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-dotnet-client